# Imageview.setMaxHeight is working wrong

Tags: android

Hy!

I download a picture from the internet and want to display it. The height should be 1/6 of the max screen height (for multi phone support)

**Code:**

```
final ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);

iv.setMaxHeight(getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight()/6);
```

Please help!

Comment: Did you try logging the height to make sure it is being returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `layout_weight` attribute of `LinearLayout` to divide the screen into the parts you need. The ratio of the values you set to the different parts makes the parts become bigger or smaller.